# How to change PDF rendering engine?

Tags: cocoa, pdf, transparency, gradient

In my Cocoa application I need to create PDF that contains gradients with transparency.
At the moment PDF 1.4 is available to Cocoa applications for printing or exporting to PDF.

But this version has some limitations, for example, I can't create gradients with transparency.

Is it possible to switch default PDF rendering engine or somehow create PDF file with gradients that contains transparency?